# Firefox narrate (text to speech) not showing all voices

Tags: windows-10, firefox, audio, text-to-speech

In version 49, [Firefox added a text-to-speech](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/49.0/releasenotes/) function to its reader mode. On Windows it works well with Microsoft-provided voices (namely Microsoft Zira Desktop or Microsoft David Desktop), but other voices cannot be used as they do not show in the list.

Those voices I would like to use are provided by third parties and are SAPI5 compatible. I tried to fiddle with Firefox settings in 'about:config' and found nothing interesting except for **narrate.filter-voices**, which allows to show all voices, irrespective of the language.

Is there a way to make SAPI5 voices show up in Firefox ?

Comment: Linux counterpart question with some more info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/953509/how-can-i-change-the-voice-used-by-firefox-reader-view-narrator-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I managed to show all installed languages and thus seleted one of them (Polish) gaining success with hearing website being read aloud in Firefox! 
I went to `about:config`, typed (searched for) `narrate` an then changed setting `narrate.filter-voices` from `true` (defalut) to `false`